# ASP.NET active directory membership using VPN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership, vpn, activedirectorymembership

I trying to use ASP.NET Active Directory Membership Provider for authenticating the users in ASP.NET Web API. This active directory is on a different server and I can only connect to that server through VPN. Following is the code I am using:

web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://vpn.servername.com/dc=vpn,dc=servername,dc=com"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
         connectionProtection="Secure"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
         enableSearchMethods="false" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

c#:

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

It throws an exception that it cannot make a secure connection to the server and inner most exception message is that server is not operational. I am also connected to this VPN using Cisco AnyConnect and its working fine.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally have similar problems. My experience is that it's usually a name resolution issue with the connection string.

1. Check the innermost exception to see if you get a `The server is not operational` exception. If so your name resolution for vpn.servername.com is probably not resolving to your Active Directory server;
2. Trying a ping using that name to see if it resolves;
3. Be sure that your server name is the AD domain controller. For me the name looks like servername.domain.local.